# unexpected EOF while parsing python def

Tags: python, eof

When I want to compile this script I get the 'unexpected EOF while parsing' error.

```
import alpaca_trade_api as tradeapi

Alpaca_Base_URL = "https://paper-api.alpaca.markets";

    class PythonTradingBot:
      def __init__(self):
        self.alpaca = tradeapi.REST(API_KEY, API_SECRET, Alpaca_Base_URL, api_version='v2')
      def run(self):
```

Does someone know what is wrong and how I can ifx it?

Comment: Please share the relevant part of the error (the line that triggers the error at least).

Comment: Your `run` method has no body. Simply adding `pass` will resolve it

Comment: Your indentation is wrong, but that could be a typo in the question.

Comment: The error message when I debug:
line 14
    def run(self):
                 ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing